# Alhfors problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading the book "Complex Variable" from Alhfors, and I don't know how to solve this problem. I hope someone could help me:

If $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z|<1$ and $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{1-|z|} $, find a best estimation for $|f^{(n)}(0)|$ than the Cauchy inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cauchy formula provides that, for every $\varrho\in(0,1)$, 
$$
f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=\varrho}\frac{f(\zeta)\,d\zeta}{\zeta^{n+1}}.
$$
Hence
$$
\lvert\, f^{(n)}(0)\rvert\le \frac{n!}{\varrho^{n}}\max_{\lvert\zeta\rvert=\varrho}\lvert\, f(\zeta)\rvert\le \frac{n!}{\varrho^n(1-\varrho)}.
$$
Thus
$$
\lvert\, f^{(n)}(0)\rvert\le \inf_{\varrho\in(0,1)}\frac{n!}{\varrho^n(1-\varrho)}.
$$
It can be readily shown that, the infimum of $\frac{n!}{\varrho^n(1-\varrho)}$ is achieved for $\varrho=\frac{n}{n+1}$. Hence
$$
\lvert\, f^{(n)}(0)\rvert\le \frac{(n+1)!(n+1)^n}{n^n}.
$$